# Sound Effects? Mixer

Tags: audio, signal-processing

Ok right I have a voice recorder which records whatever the user plays, says etc

Is there anyway where i can have effects such as 'slow motion voice' or just like changing the sound effects. Or the 'bass' drops or something

So like a Mixer.

Comment: You'll probably get a better response if you ask about a specific effect.  You might start with this list for ideas.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_effect#Techniques

Comment: Sound effects and mixing are two completely separate topics. You probably want to drop the term "mixer" form your question as it appears that what you're actually interested in is sound effects.

Comment: I would vote this question down, but I'm giving some slack due to obvious inexperience using this site. Tags don't relate to question; the question is too broad; poorly explained question, etc. etc.

Comment: What languages are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking into [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) for your audio library.  You can use it with many languages.  It has sample code for some of the functionality you are looking for, and is a good way to get started.